# Минимизировать стоимость трубопровода подбором координаты

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Задача о строительстве газового трубопровода

Дана последовательность расстояний расположения домов от шоссе.
Нужно рассчитать расположение газового трубопровода, чтобы стоимость подключения всех домов была минимальна.
Все дома находятся по одну сторону от шоссе. Возможен случай, когда расстояние от дома до шоссе равно 0.

Газовый трубопровод будет строиться параллельно шоссе

```
func calculateLocation(houses []uint) float
```

Что хочется увидеть:

Алгоритм со сложностью O(N) по времени

Comment: Если я правильно понял условие, то нужно тупо найти среднее арифметическое от всех расстояний.

Comment: @Xander, а если я правильно понимаю условие (а вообще-то я не уверен, что я его понимаю), то среднее - неправильно. Вот пример: 1, 2, 3, 94 - среднее арифметическое 25. Сумма 24+23+22+69 = 138. А если строить в 2, то будет 1+0+1+92=94.

Comment: Вообще похоже на задачу регрессии. Тогда надо среднеквадратичное отклонение минимизировать )

Comment: @CrazyElf, сомнительно. У задачи есть точное решение, причём цена линейная, а не квадратичная. Сумму модулей (которая и есть стоимость) надо минимизировать. Не верю, что если все слагаемые возвести в квадрат, то минимум останется в той же точке.

Comment: Газопровод расположен между шоссе и домами или дом может быть между газопроводом и шоссе?

Comment: @AndyPavlov, было бы крайне странно располагать все дома с одной стороны. К тому же, в таком случае ответ - первый дом, а цена sum(a)-len(a)*min(a).

Comment: @AndyPavlov, ну условие кривовато сформулировано, но именно этот момент у меня вопросов не вызывал. Я сначала думал, что задача вообще одномерная, пока про параллельность не прочитал... Но как решить без сортировки у меня идей нет. PS: я исправил формулу в своём комменте.

Comment: Сводится к поиску медианы. Решается за линейное время.

Comment: В задаче недостаточно данных. Как верно заметил Qwetiy - в текущей формулировке, задача одномерна.

Comment: Не успел ответить. Куда девать диссертацию?

Answer (score 1):

Если надо подобрать `x` чтобы минимизировать

```
abs(x-a[0]) + abs(x-a[1]) + ... + abs(x-a[n-1])
```

Как это сделать за O(n) я не знаю, но могу за O(n*lb(n)):

1. Сортируем массив `a` и считаем его сумму `r`
2. Представим трубу в позиции `p=0`. Цена слева от трубы будет `l=0`, а справа `r`
3. Пройдём по массиву, текущий элемент `x` имеет индекс `i`, pзначение предыдущего `p`

   ```
   l += i * (x-p)
   r -= (n-i) * (x-p)
   ```
4. Выбираем максимум среди всех пройденных сумм `l+r`

https://ideone.com/esdLjV

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 94]

a.sort()
n = len(a)

l = 0
p = 0
r = sum(a)

res = r
pos = 0

for i,x in enumerate(a):
  l += i * (x-p)
  r -= (n-i) * (x-p)
  cur = l + r
  p = x
  
  if cur < res:
    res = cur
    pos = x
  
print(pos, res)
```

PS: Почему достаточно посматривать только точки с домами, можно подумать самостоятельно.

Comment: Проверьте что минимум достигается на медиане (если больше домов снизу, то выгоднее двигать вниз, если сверху - то вверх, если сверху и снизу одинаково - это минимум).

Comment: Медиана ищется за линейное время без сортировки.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, прикольно. Пожалуй, согласен. Опубликуй ответом.